# How to roll up into Any and then unroll into the generic type in scala

Tags: scala

As you roll up something like instances of `Flag[T]`, you end up rolling into `Flag[_]` or `Flag[Any]` like so

```
val seq: Seq[Flag[_]] = new Flag[Int](5) :+ new Flag[MyFlag](someinstance) :+ new Flag[String]("stringValue")
```

so inside `Flag`, I added a

```
def genericType(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Class[_] = m.runtimeClass
```

We also have inside the `Flag` class a

```
def value: T = { //the value }}
```

so now as I loop over `Flag[_]`, I need to pass value and `classOf[T]` into a template function

```
def someTemplateFunction[F](clazz: Class[F], value: F)
```

How can I achieve this? and should I be using `[_]`, `[Any]` or `[Nothing]`?

I finally got something that compiles but had to use a Java function like so to get there (about to test it all out as I am not sure it will work at all):

```
public class BindGuiceByType {
    public static void bind(Binder binder, String flagName, Object value, Class clazz) {
        Key key = Key.get(clazz, new FlagImpl(flagName));
        binder.bind(key).toInstance(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the only way to do all this in a type safe manner would be to use something like Shapeless HLists and Polymorphic function values.

Comment: `someTemplateFunction` does what? returns what? Is the type parameter `F` a `Flag`?

Comment: @m-z someTemplateFunction binds each value in guice so the return value is :Unit.  It's basically binding all the program arguments to their typed value(ie. not as a String unless Flag[String] is declared)

Comment: in fact, the someTemplateFunction real implementation I am trying to use is the one I wrote in java right there, but so far m.runtimeClass is only returning java.lang.Object which is quite annoying.